WebStorm (TypeScript) does not see certain imports, why?
I have a line with the discordJS
import {ChatInputCommandInteraction, Guild, Snowflake, ChannelType} from "discord.js";

WebStorm highlights ChannelType import as incorrect. I.e. shows error, although DiscordJS has it, and no errors occur when compiling the code
Так же и с "GatewayIntentBits"
import {ChatInputCommandInteraction, Client, GatewayIntentBits} from "discord.js";

(Sorry for any possible incorrect tags)
Before, everything was normal. Sometimes this happened, but it was fixed by the usual rollback to the old version of Discord.JS. Now whatever I do, it’s all a mess
